# Custion javascript calculation increases 10 levels instead of increasing 1?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this custom code I'm working on as a pet project, and I've been bug testing it and I *thought* I had finally gotten it to a point where I could clone it with other options, but apparently not? So when you give enough xp in current xp to roll over to level two, for example, level 1 requires 180 XP to roll over to level 2, and then it takes 360 for level 3, however... if I put in current existing xp is 180 and new xp gains as 0 it jumps up to level 11. I've included a picture for a visual of this error, it also does this for level 2 and I would assume all levels. Can anyone help me fix this weird error? This is the first time I've tried to code something in javascript before so I appreciate any assistance as a newbie to the language!

EDIT: As it turns out testing the code itself doesn't produce the right results either, I did fix the typo mentioned, and it still doesn't produce the right results in a normal scenario and I'm not sure why either.

Image example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEJ47.png

The javascript itself

```
var xpToLevel = [180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1260, 1440, 1620, 1800, 1980, 2160, 2340, 2520, 2700, 2880, 3060, 3240, 3420, 3600, 3780, 3960, 4140, 4320, 4500, 4680, 4860, 5040, 5220, 5400, 5580, 5760, 5940, 6120, 6300, 6480, 6660, 6840, 7020, 7200, 7380, 7560, 7740, 7920, 8100, 8280, 8460, 8640, 8820, 9000, 9180, 9360, 9540, 9720, 9900, 10080, 10260, 10440, 10620, 10800, 10980, 11160, 11340, 11520, 11700, 11880, 12060, 12240, 12420, 12600, 12780, 12960, 13140, 13320, 13500, 13680, 13860, 14040, 14220, 14400, 14580, 14760, 14940, 15120, 15300, 15480, 15660, 15840, 16020, 16200, 16380, 16560, 16740, 16920, 17100, 17280, 17460, 17640, 17820
],
xpToNext,
newXp,
currentLevel,
currentXp,
currentSpareXp,
goalLevel,
levelBaseXp,
nextLevelXp,
totalXp, 
spareXp,
xpToGoal,
trainerBattle,
officialWin,
officialLoss,
wildPokemon = '<p>Enter your current level, Current XP, and new XP to add in. The new level and new remaining XP will be displayed.</p><p><b>Your Level:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="100" onKeyUp="inputFullLevel(this, this.value)" id="currentLevel"><br> <b>Current XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="0" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputSpareXp(this, this.value)" id="currentXp"><br><b>New XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputXp(this, this.value)" id="newXp"></p><button class="forminput" type="button" onclick="runWildPokemon()">Calculate</button>';


   function switchCalc() {
      var c = document.getElementById("calc_select"),
        calcActive = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
      document.getElementById("calc-desc").innerHTML = eval(calcActive);
      document.getElementById("calc-results").innerHTML = '';
            }
    
  function runWildPokemon(){
    currentLevel = document.getElementById("currentLevel").value;
    currentXp = document.getElementById("currentXp").value;
    newXp = document.getElementById("newXp").value;
    const cb = document.getElementById('xpShare');
    const cb2 = document.getElementById('luckyEgg');
    console.log(cb.checked);
    xpToNext = xpToLevel[currentLevel - 1];
    newTotalXp = parseInt(newXp) + parseInt(currentXp);
    newTotalXp *= 0.5;
    
    if (document.getElementById("xpShare").checked == true) {
      newTotalXp *= 0.5;
    }
   
    if (document.getElementById("luckyEgg").checked == true) {
      newTotalXp *= 1.5;
    }
    
    newTotalXp = Math.trunc(newTotalXp);
    
    while(currentXp >= xpToNext) {
      currentXp = currentXp - xpToNext;
      currentLevel = currentLevel + 1;
      xpToNext = xpToLevel[currentLevel - 1];
    }
    document.getElementById("calc-results").innerHTML = '<b>Level:</b> ' + currentLevel +'   <b>XP:</b> ' + '[' + newTotalXp + '/' + xpToNext + ']';
  }

        function inputXp(field, input) {
    if (input > 17820) {
    field.value = 17820;
    }
            if (input < 0) {
    field.value = 0;
        }
    }
        function inputSpareXp(field, input) {
        if (input > 17819) {
    field.value = 17819;
    }
            if (input < 0) {
    field.value = 0;
        }
    }
        function inputFullLevel(field, input) {
        if (input > 100) {
    field.value = 100;
    }
            if (input <= 0) {
    field.value = 1;
        }
    }
        function inputLevel(field, input) {
        if (input > 99) {
    field.value = 99;
    }
            if (input <= 0) {
    field.value = 1;
        }
    }
```

The HTML

```
<div id="calculator">
<span id="calcActive" class="wildPokemon"> <b>Select Encounter Type:</b><br> <select class="forminput" id="calc_select" onChange="switchCalc()" style="margin-bottom: 10px;text-align:center;">
  
          <option selected="selected" value="wildPokemon">Wild Pokemon</option>
          <option value="trainerBattle">Trainer/Social</option>
          <option value="officialWin">Official Battle Win</option>
          <option value="officialLoss">Official Battle Loss</option>
        </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="xpShare" name="xpShare" value="xpShare">
<label for="xpShare"><b>XP Share</b></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="luckyEgg" name="luckyEgg" value="luckyEgg">
<label for="luckyEgg"><b>Lucky Egg</b></label><br>
        </span><br>
 <div id="calc-desc">
<p>Enter your current level, Current XP, and new XP to add in. The new level and new remaining XP will be displayed.</p><p><b>Your Level:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="100" onKeyUp="inputFullLevel(this, this.value)" id="currentLevel"><br> <b>Current XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="0" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputSpareXp(this, this.value)" id="currentXp"><br><b>New XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputXp(this, this.value)" id="newXp"></p><button class="forminput" type="button" onclick="runWildPokemon()">Calculate</button>

  </div><p>
  
  </p>
 
 <div id="calc-results">

 </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#calculator{
width: 300px;
background: var(--back1);
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
border: 10px solid var(--outline);
}
#calc-desc {font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;}

#calc-results b{
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
}
#calc-results {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
font-size: 25px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a typo!

You search for the element with id `currentLevel`

```
currentLevel = document.getElementById("currentLevel").value;
```

But in your HTML it's named `currentlevel`

```
<input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="100" onKeyUp="inputFullLevel(this, this.value)" id="currentlevel">
```

JavaScript is case sensitive! Thus, you never get the current level's value for your computation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a function to calculate the XP to upgrade instead of a huge array and your current incrementation method. The XP to reach level up is just 180 * current level. Therefore, calculate the XP it takes to get to a level as 90*(n^2+n).

Then just add together the XP to get to the current level, and the new XP (after the luckyEgg and xpShare stuff), and then calculate the level that the new XP corresponds to.

Something like:

```
currentLevel = document.getElementById("currentLevel").value;
currentLevel = parseInt(currentLevel);
currentXp = document.getElementById("currentXp").value;
newXp = document.getElementById("newXp").value;
const cb = document.getElementById('xpShare');
const cb2 = document.getElementById('luckyEgg');
const curXp = 90*((currentLevel*currentLevel)+currentLevel);
newTotalXp = parseInt(newXp) + parseInt(currentXp);
newTotalXp *= 0.5;

if (document.getElementById("xpShare").checked == true) {
  newTotalXp *= 0.5;
}
   
if (document.getElementById("luckyEgg").checked == true) {
  newTotalXp *= 1.5;
}
    
newTotalXp = Math.trunc(newTotalXp);
    
const newLevelXp = newTotalXp + curXp;
return Math.floor((((newLevelXp/90)+2) ** 0.5) - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm really new to javascript, and looking at this I'm not really sure I follow it as well, do you think you can explain it a bit more? I'm just a complete and total novice I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: This isn’t as much a javascript concept as just a math concept. All the XP upgrades follow a pattern 180*current level. So to reach a given level, you need to achieve 180*1+180*2+180*3+...+180*L XP in total. That simplifies to 180*(sum of digits from 1 through L). It is a known math equation that the sum of digits 1 through n is (n^2 + n)/2, thus XP=90(L^2 + L). You can use this equation, and the inverse obtained by completing the square to solve for level given XP L=sqrt((XP/90)+2)-1